# Randomly missing html brackets, swelling memory usage

Tags: php, apache

I'm running Windows 7 with WAMP -- PHP 5.3.8 and Apache 2.2.21 on my laptop. I'm also using APC. Just last night and today I've noticed some very strange behavior that I'm trying to figure out.

First, there are randomly missing html "<" angle brackets missing in the generated page. It seems to be coming from  tags. The tags are returned from a very basic 5 line function. I've checked it many times, and it shouldn't be producing a missing bracket.

Even more strange is that it only does it randomly, and it hasn't yet been the same html tag twice. I've been reloading and running the html code through the W3C validator without making any changes to the code and can't make it happen twice in a row.

The second thing is that this morning memory_get_peak_usage() reported that my scripts were using around 25MB each, which is far from ordinary. I restarted WAMP, and they went back to using 1-1.5MB each.

I don't know if these two occurrences are related. Has anyone seen this?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, but its worth noting that it isn't the same PHP function producing the weird tags. There are a couple of different ones for different data, but all basically the same function.

2nd Edit: Here's the most recent functions where it happened:

```
function ampm_tags($value) 
{
    if ($value == 1) { 
        return '
            <option></option>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">AM</option>
            <option value="2">PM</option>'; 
    }
    elseif ($value == 2) { 
        return '
            <option></option>        
            <option value="1">AM</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">PM</option>'; 
    }    
    else { 
        return '
            <option></option>
            <option value="1">AM</option>
            <option value="2">PM</option>'; 
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you show us one of the functions?

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: The most recent looked like this: `<option value="1">AM/option>` This is the exact tag produced by the function above.

Comment: This might sound odd but try replacing the double quotes with escaped single quotes and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, just tested, it worked:

```
function ampm_tags($value) 
{
    $str ='
        <option></option>
        <option value="1"'.($value == 1 ? ' selected="selected" ' : '').'>AM</option>
        <option value="2"'.($value == 2 ? ' selected="selected" ' : '').'>PM</option>';
    return $str;
}
```

Just for info: 
I use ZendServer CE latest release. PHP Version 5.3.9-ZS5.6.0

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I don't think the issue is with the function. I've used it many times with no problems, and the fact that it occurs with no obvious pattern leads me to believe it's something else.

Comment: Then, there is something else on your wamp which is not discussed here.Which IDE you are using?Did you try to run code on other server?Did you consider some debugger?

Comment: My wamp setup is almost completely standard. The only adjustment I've made to any component is enabling APC (not recently, a long time before this). The only sort of IDE I use is Notepad++ for editing code. I have error reporting on strict.  All my code seems to work perfectly, except for this occasional occurrence. The strangest part is that it doesn't happen very often, and there seems to be no patten whatsoever.